# Set NSViewController to fullscreen

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

My ViewController contains a button. When button is pressed it execute this lines:

```
self.window?.styleMask = NSFullScreenWindowMask
self.window?.setFrame((NSScreen.mainScreen()?.frame)!, display: true, animate: true)
self.window?.contentViewController = Game()
```

Ideally, when button is pressed, the windows content is replaced with new NSViewController called Game.

Even if window is animated to became fullscreen, Game is shown in screen corner (is only 500*300px) and the window isn't in fullscreen mode. How can I change content of the window and set its in fullscreen style?

Comment: Are you using Autolayout?

Comment: @rocky no, i'm not using autolayout

Answer (score 0):

Just set the autoresizing mask of your NSView to be width and height sizable:

```
self.view.autoresizingMask = NSViewHeightSizable | NSViewWidthSizable;
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I was informed of this answer:

```
let currentBounds = contentViewController!.view.bounds.size
let destVCNew = destVC as? CPViewController
// Important, missing part:
destVCNew?.view.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: currentBounds)
self.contentViewController = destVCNew
```